# Build HTTP GET request with headers and body PHP

Tags: php, rest, api, http, get

I need to retrieve order information from an API. This API needs to be authenticated to get a session token, which is used in all other API requests. Im not sure how to construct this request to include both an authentication and the request I want to make. Below is from the documentation:

> The authenticate API returns a session token that is required to
>   access any of the other APIs. APIs require an HTTP header of
>   Authorization and a value of Bearer {session-token}

Sample Authenticate Request: https://api.whatever.com/api/v5/authenticate?apiKey=my-API-key 
 Which returns:

> {
>       "sessionToken":"UniqueSessionTokenHere"
>   }

Sample request I need to make: https://api.whatever.com/api/v5/inventory?itemNumber=ABC12345
Which should return inventory information but is just returning  this message:

> Authorization has been denied for this request.

How can I combine these to allow me to make the inventory request I need to make? I assume I would use cURL, but I cant quite figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl_setopt() with `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to set custom headers.

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.co.in");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'sessionToken:UniqueSessionTokenHere'
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```